# How to convert google mlkit Face object to bitmap

Tags: android, face-detection, google-mlkit

Google's Mlkit(not firebase mlkit) provides face object after detecting a face successfully. But how to convert it to either bitmap or image file after detection?

Comment: Would you still have access to the image you started with (that was provided to MLkit)?

Comment: No, As it is frame based. I'm using Camera Preview and giving frames to MLKit

Answer (score 0):

You may check the [ML kit example](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/c57e14385d4dedea057bfab1032f897564b1636f/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/facedetector/FaceGraphic.java#L35) to see how to draw the result on a preview frame.